# Login function saving token to localStorage as [Object][Object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backend

I am trying to login to my user account which is saved on database and attach a token to that username with 'jwt-token'.

```
router.post('/users/login', (req, res) => {
  User.authenticate()(req.body.username, req.body.password, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { console.log(err) }
    res.json(user ? jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET) : null)
  })
})
```

However when i login to the account, the token is being saved, as [Object][Object] in the local storage via this function here,

```
  // when a user clicks login
  const handleLogin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('/api/users/login', {
      username: userState.username,
      password: userState.password
    }).then(token => {
      console.log(token)
      setLoginState(true)
      localStorage.setItem('username', userState.username)
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)

    }).catch(err => { console.log(err) })
```

What is the reason the token is saving as an object? is it not properly being created by my route? or am I not calling it correctly in my `.then` call? any insight would be appreciated. Still trying to learn as much as i can on backend work and seem to hit problems at every step.

Comment: `localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify('token', token));` and `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token', token));`.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/9824103

Comment: I realize afteer the fact that when i was console.log`ing the token it was spitting out an object. by Setting the ```localStorage.setItem('token', token.data)``` i was able to fix the issue

Comment: Really good question. I'm sure everyone will find results when they research beer. But I'm sharing it so it won't be a waste of time, because I wasted my time. Reason: not being able to actually write the token value to localStorage. Let's Debug There

Answer (score 2):

We have to stringify while storing objects in storage and parse the stored objects while retrieving.

```
// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(username));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedUsername= localStorage.getItem('username');
console.log('retrievedUsername: ', JSON.parse(retrievedUsername));
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.setItem()` saves information as Strings which is why you see "*[Object][Object]*" being saved since that is what it is receiving.

So you need to transform your object to a String before you save it.

You can achieve this by using the `JSON.stringify()` function.

Note: you will have to transform the String back to an object when you need to get it.
You can achieve this by using the `JSON.parse()`

Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(userState.username))
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token))

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('username'))
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

Answer (score 0):

axios promise returns response object which has a data attribute. To access token you should call
`res.data`
and store it like so
`localStorage.setItem('token',res.data)`